# Line between two elements following a path

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, html5-canvas

Im looking for a library or example of code that can help me doing this :

The position will be updated with some data to set the first position and so on. I have been searching for a while and looked into jQuery connection, jsPlumb and JScytoscape but nothing concrete.

[image]

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there a Library or example that link two div with a line that follow a path.

Comment: A straight line from div A to div B?

Comment: If you look at the image that I join with my post I talk about the line between the little white circle and the square containing an avatar picture and each dot are going from the start to the finish following the inner blue line. Like a race between avatar.